# ClassNotFoundException when using instance? on a defrecord type in Clojure

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

I've written a function that selects only the keys of a map that are named in a specific [schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema):

```
(ns foo.schema
  (:require [schema.core :as s]))

(defn select-schema
  "Given a schema and a map m, selects only the keys of m that are named in the schema."
  [m schema]
  (let [optional? #(instance? schema.core.OptionalKey %)
        wildcard? #(= s/Keyword %)]
    (if (some wildcard? (keys schema))
      m  ; the schema allows any keyword as a key, so just return the map
      (let [ks (->> schema keys (map #(if (optional? %) (:k %) %)))]
        (select-keys m ks)))))
```

This works just fine in my unit tests:

```
(testing "Required key and wildcard"
    (let [schema {:foo s/Str, s/Keyword s/Any}]
      (is (= {:foo "Yup", :bar 42, :baz true} (select-schema {:foo "Yup", :bar 42, :baz true} schema)))
      (is (= {:foo "Yup", :bar 42} (select-schema {:foo "Yup", :bar 42} schema)))
      (is (= {:foo "Yup"} (select-schema {:foo "Yup"} schema)))))
```

However, when I use `foo.schema/select-schema` in a completely separate project (i.e. `lein install` in my foo project to build a jar and stick it in my `~/.m2/repository` and name it as a dependency), I get a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, compiling:(insurrection/test/handler.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at foo.schema__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at foo.schema__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: schema.core.OptionalKey
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    ...
```

I looked at the Prismatic Schema source and found that `OptionalKey` is a defrecord type. A little Googling revealed that defrecord generates a Java class, which sometimes needs to be imported after requiring the namespace that defines it, but trying to do that in the project  that contains `foo.schema` doesn't make any difference: it works in the unit tests, but doesn't work in the other project that uses `foo` as a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

You imported `schema.core` as `s`. If that's the exact code you're running, you should probably be using `#(instance? s/OptionalKey %)` as your `optional?` function.

Not to mention `schema` is a local variable (argument) in `select-schema`.

Comment: `instance?` works on Java types, so it knows not of Clojure namespaces and aliasing with `require ... :as s`. I don't understand your second statement about `schema` being a local variable (AKA binding) in `select-schema`. Is that causing problems?

Comment: Nevermind that, I'm being an idiot. In that case, your problem probably is that whatever jar defines schema.core.OptionalKey isn't on your classpath when running the separate project.

Comment: Do you have any idea why that would be? I have prismatic/schema defined as a dependency in both the foo project (that contains the above function) *and* the separate project that depends on foo.